# Tree data set migration to CQ/AEM

Tags: java, data-structures, aem, crx

I have a data set(excel spreadsheet) which needs to be migrated to CQ/AEM. 
eg:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLQ8z.jpg

Each entry in the excel cell should correspond to a node in CRX content repository. My initial thought is to use apache POI to parse the excel and construct a data structure containing the tree elements. Now, How do i construct this tree data structure before iterating persisting to CRX? Map containing map containing map(depth of 5) will be very complex to manage.
If there is any efficient design idea that you can share, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To construct tree element you can create a class Node.
Class Node will have reference of its parent, reference of list of child nodes and actual Node data (corresponding to jcr node)

By using this class you can create a tree structure.
Use DFS/BFS to traverse the tree and then convert those node to jcr Nodes.

Comment: I'll give this option a try today and share an update. Any idea if there is any OOTB data structure which will cater to the above scenario ?